# заменить четные строки двумерного массива одномерным массивом

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Функция check проверяет является,ли номер строки нечетным

```
bool check(int i)
{

if (i % 2 != 0)
    return true;
}
```

Функция fill меняет элемент двумерного массива на соответствующий элемент одномерного

```
int fill(int**mas, int*mas1, int i, int j)
{
mas[i][j] = mas1[i];
return mas[i][j];
} 



for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (check(i) ==true)
        {
            mas[i][j] = fill(mas, mas1, i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: нечетные строки]

так все работает. почему же не работает, когда я аналогичным образом хочу заменить четные строки?

```
bool check(int i)
 {
if (i % 2 == 0)
    return true;
 }
```

[image: четные строки]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скажите, а что ваша функция возвращает при `i%2 != 0` ?

```
bool check(int i)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        return true;
 }
```

Как оно вообще у вас скомпилировалось? Ведь явно же были предупреждение - почему вы ему не вняли?

Comment: не было предупреждения

Comment: @choko меняйте компилятор)

Comment: Или добавляйте ключик... А чем компилировали-то?

Comment: @Harry локальный отладчик windows в microsoft visual studio

Comment: Странно. Смотрите тут - http://i90.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0117/84/b40546d8f4a1e45148248dd090eb9584.jpg - создал со всеми стандартными настройками. Видите подчеркнутое красным? Это и есть предупреждение к вашей функции. Неужели у вас такого предупреждения не было?

Answer (score 0):

Данная функция

```
bool check(int i)
{

if (i % 2 != 0)
    return true;
}
```

имеет неопределенное поведение, так как она ничего не возвращает в случае, когда число `i` является четным.

Кроме того, у вас в задании написано, что нужно заменить все строки с четными номерами, тогда как в данном цикле

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (check(i) ==true)
        {
            mas[i][j] = fill(mas, mas1, i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

имеет место попытка заменить все нечетные строки двумерного массива.

Кроме того нет никакого смысла пытаться передать в эту функцию двумерный массив

```
int fill(int**mas, int*mas1, int i, int j)
{
mas[i][j] = mas1[i];
return mas[i][j];
}
```

Во-первых, типы аргумента и параметра не совместимы, если аргумент - это действительно двумерный массив, а не одномерный массив указателей на первые элемент одномерных массивов. А, во-вторых, достаточно передать в функцию одну сроку двумерного массива, чтобы ее заполнить, а не весь двумерный массив. И, в-третьих, в теле функции вы лишь пытаетесь присвоить один элемент, а не всю строку. Это большого смысла не имеет.

Исходя из всего сказанного, соответствующие функции могут быть определены следующим образом:

```
bool is_even( int i )
{
    return i % 2 == 0;
}
```

Фукнция `fill` может выглядеть следующим образом

```
void fill( int *mas, const int *mas1, int n )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) mas[i] = mas1[i];
}
```

Тогда цикл программы будут такими

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if ( is_even( i ) ) fill( mas[i], mas1, n );
}
```

Можно было бы не писать функцию `is_even`, так как известно, что четные индексы - это 0, 2, и т.д.

Поэтому можно было бы просто написать

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i +=2)
{
    fill( mas[i], mas1, n );
}
```

Вместо собственной функции `fill` можно использовать стандартный алгоритм `std::copy`, объявленный в заголовке `<algorithm>`

Тогда бы все выглядело очень просто. Включаете щзаголовок

```
#include <algorithm>

//...
```

и написать цикл

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i +=2)
{
    std::copy( mas1, mas1 + n, mas[i] );
}
```